# how do use a Python colormap in two directions

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have some data that I am trying to plot, that goes from -1 to 0 to 1 and I would like to use a color bar such as "Viridis" but I would like to have the same colors run from -1 (yellow) to 0 (purple), and then flip directions and from from 0 (purple) to 1 (yellow). Essentially have the purple in the middle at 0 and have the exact same transitions in colors for 0 to -1 and 0 to 1. In this instance I could just have the values has aboslute values but moving forward with the code, I wont be able to do that for a variety of reasons.

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the colors from reversed viridis into a list, and then extend this list with its reversed version:

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

colors = [plt.cm.viridis_r(a) for a in np.linspace(0,1,100)]
colors = colors + colors[::-1]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)


x = range(100)

plt.scatter(x,x,c=x, cmap=cmap)
```

[image]

Comment: or simply `cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(plt.cm.viridis_r.colors + plt.cm.viridis.colors)`

Comment: I agree that this is simpler.

Comment: Excellent! in my code in ended up using @Stef's solution because it was simpler, but Warped's solution just gave me a few ideas for other things!

Comment: @Stef, Im actually to just change the colormap from viridis to say "YlGnBu" and keep getting the error "LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'colors" - this seems to be happening with any colorbar other than viridis....am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: @Stef....yeah just typed what you had and it works great, I do the same thing with "Blues" and it doesn't....

Comment: @NightLearner: I see, my simplification only works for `ListedColormap`s like viridis or plasma, not for `LinearSegmentedColormap`s like Blues or YlGnBu. In this case you'll have to extract the colors as shown in the answer. See https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html for the different kinds of colormaps.

Comment: @Stef....got it, makes total sense. Just tried our Warped's soloution on other color bars and works well.....always great to have multiple options!